# When i open a image with imread function of OpenCV, why does it has a border?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, border, imread

source image:

[image]

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                            tr("Open Image"),".",
                                            tr("Image Files(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
image = cv::imread(fileName.toUtf8().data());
if(!image.data){
    qDebug()<< "Could not open or find the image";
    return ;
}
QString status = QString::number(image.rows) + "x" +        
QString::number(image.cols);
ui->label_2->setText(status);
//show 
cv::namedWindow("Original Image");
cv::imshow("Original Image",image);
```

image result:

[image]

**I can't understand this situration,Where is the problem?**

Comment: The resulting image also has statistics in the lower pane.  Where did that come from?

Comment: I am a beginner, the picture is from the network, I use the opencv2.4.11,

Comment: What's the mean of "come from"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , that's a feature of the opencv qt gui bindings (an overlay, not part of the original img)

Comment: but i change the size of image(based the source image),the result haven't the border,How to explain this?

Comment: I guess the original Image has an additional **alpha** channel, but while reading the image using `imread()` it simply reads only RGB channels for reading a full RGBA image you need to pass an additional parameter `-1` to the method `imread()` as `image = cv::imread(fileName.toUtf8().data(), -1);`, If still the problem persists then I guess there is some issue with `fileName.toUtf8().data()`

Comment: i used the method imread() as image = cv::imread(fileName.toUtf8().data(), -1); the result is the same. fileName.toUtf8().data() is only a path of the image...,i can read the image,then i don't think there is some issue with the path...

Comment: use imread with -1 then print img.channels() if it is 4 please use cvtColor(...,..., CV_BGRA2BGR) before displaying.

Comment: You can simply use **image = imread("image_path", -1).**

Comment: @Micka I used the method that you said,but the result is also the same...

Comment: @SagarPatel  yes,I used this method at the beginning. I also used the method that Micka said, there is also a border with the result

Comment: why you are using .toUtf8.data() ?

Comment: can you try to create a new qt label and render it as rgba image? opencv rwally has problems with displaying alpha channels. converting to bgr probably is just the same there...